# How to truncate the axis name in echarts

Tags: echarts

I try to have a truncated axis name for yAxis in echarts without success. Even setting the `overflow` option to `truncated`, which should render ellipsis a the end has no effect, same for setting a short width. The setting looks like this:

```js
nameTextStyle:{
  overflow : 'truncate',
  align:'left',
  ellipsis :'...',
}
```

example can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-line-chart-pryr13?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nameTruncate` would work:

```
yAxis: {
  type: "value",
  name: "very very very very very very long axis name",

  nameTruncate: {
    maxWidth: 100,
    ellipsis: "..."
  }
},
```

which results into:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, any idea why this is not documented?

Comment: honestly IDK, based on Echarts repository on Github, it's been there for at least 3 years, https://github.com/apache/echarts/blob/9c4b7423e7cd0727f5f648b720f151885aee53a4/src/coord/axisCommonTypes.ts#L42